# How to create archive pages for metadata query generated posts (so without taxonomy)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

It is a bit complicated to formulate (or maybe just I'am so tired now), but I trying will be clear:

I want creating archive pages for liked posts by users. This will be similar to author pages, like:

```
 author pages: domain.tld/author/%USER%/(page/x/)
 liked pages: domain.tld/likedby/%USER%/(page/x/)
```

I can get these liked posts by the current user with my sql query, like this (I use the wp_ulike plugin):

```
 $sql =  "
 SELECT * FROM wp_ulike WHERE user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
 AND status = 'like'
 ORDER BY wp_ulike.date_time DESC
 LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . $post_per_page . "; "; 

 $user_logs = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT );
```

But, how can I create a page template, like `category.php`, `tag.php` or `author.php`, to my metadata query, so how can I make a template (like `likedby.php`), what generating dynamic pages with my all user's nick, like this: `domain.tld/likedby/%USER%/(page/x/)`?

**My first idea**, that I create a custom taxonomy (likedby) and I add my users names to this with a function, like `$tags`... So in this case, this is it, what create the dynamic pages, and I create a template for this custom taxonomy, what really use my sql query... but this not so elegant, because the taxonomy will be empty, and just need for that creating the pages... So I hope exist a targeted solution for this...

(Maybe my question not so clear, in turn I dont find anything on the net about this problem, but maybe I just use bad keywords, If you know, what is that, what I need searching, please write a comment, any idea is helpful!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple way to do this is to create a new page with the slug `likedby`, then add some rewrite rules to handle the extra parameters.

First, the query var that holds the requested username:

```
function wpd_likedby_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'likeduser';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_likedby_query_var' );
```

Then a couple of rewrite rules to handle the requests, directing them to our `likedby` page and setting the extra parameters:

```
function wpd_likedby_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'likedby/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=likedby&likeduser=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'likedby/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=likedby&likeduser=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_likedby_rules' );
```

You can then create a `page-likedby.php` template and put your custom queries in there. Use `get_query_var( 'likeduser' )` and `get_query_var( 'paged' )` to get the query parameters.

I also recommend looking at [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) for generating queries that accept unknown input.